# Language used in resource (.rc) files?

Tags: c++, winapi, resources

I'm learning win32 programming this days (c++),I'm wondering what programming language is used in resource(.rc) files? and where can I find a complete reference to this language?

Comment: None, it's a data format (and not a good one)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Resource (`.rc`) files are not written in a *programming language* per se (you can't write loops or conditionals, for example). However, the `.rc` file format is thoroughly documented by Microsoft at [About Resource Files](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa380599%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Answer (score 6):

It's "Windows Resource Script", and there is a reference here: [Resource-Definition Statements](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa381043(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: I'm sorry the SOF didn't allow me to vote up this cmment,Thanks Richie!